# How do I make a shared web hosting setup with dynamic vhosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, hosting, virtualhost

We are building a sort of shared hosting web server setup, but everything is managed by a web application on ourdomain.com which has default apache user (www-data) to access everyone’s files.

Everybody has a user_name, and their web_root is 
[some_root_folder]/[user_name]

We are creating dynamic virtual hosts using

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html#xtra-conf

as

```
[some_root_folder]/[user_name] user_name.ourdomain.com
```

we do

```
chown 770 user_name:www-data -R [some_root_folder]/[user_name]
```

We do not wish to create separate vhosts because that requires apache reload on each signup (i will ask your opinion on creating separate vhosts using mpm-itk on another entry).

**Question**

If user_michael executes:

`<?php echo file_get_contents(‘../user_george/index.php’); ?>`
on `user_michael.ourdomain.com/index.php`

Michael is able to read George’s files because both directories belong to www-data user group (otherwise our web app can’t modify them)

So: How can www-data can modify both Michael's and George's files, but they can't modify each other's, given setup above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run file_get_contents, the user which is reading the ../user_george/index.php file is the same as the web server (www-data) not the owner of the file.

PHP Safe Mode is a solution for this issue, but is deprecated. I'd recommend to check [this series](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/series-the-web-platform/) for solutions about Security in Shared Hosting.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Apache after each signup is probably not a problem. See [graceful restart](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html).

For your permission problem, if you only need php and don't want to run CGI you may want to look into [PHP Safe Mode](http://www.php.net/features.safe-mode). It's deprecated, not the best way, but easy to use.
Another way is to use [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/) to run php script as user_name instead of apache users.